# Why is log backup not truncating AG db log file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have multiple dbs in AG. I'm facing an issue with one of the db, whose data file size is about 200GB, and log file size is usually about 5GB.

The AG is 2-node with readable secondary.

We have hourly log backups.

**Since last 9 days the log is not truncating after the log backup.** This has caused the log file to grow to 95 GB, and it is growing every hour.

AG dashboard shows all green indicators.

Log reuse wait desc is AVAILABILITY REPLICA.

However:

- Log send queue and redo queue is empty
- Transaction (whenever they occur) are redone immediately on the secondary node, there is no delay
- There is no ongoing query on the readable secondary node (that could block the redo)
- There is no active transaction on primary
- There are more than 250 available worker threads on primary and secondary node
- The network between the nodes is high speed fibre and there hasn't been a downtime on the network

The above are usually the known reasons that prevent log truncation on primary node, but neither are true in my environment.

I have tried restarting SQL service on secondary node but this didn't make any difference. I cannot restart SQL services on primary node until this weekend.

Why would the log backup not truncate the db log file? What else can I check/review to identify root cause and fix this?

Output (captured at 14:08) of sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states and sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states from the primary replica for the AG with the database having the truncation issue is as follows:

| replica_id | group_id | is_local | role | role_desc | operational_state | operational_state_desc | connected_state | connected_state_desc | recovery_health | recovery_health_desc | synchronization_health | synchronization_health_desc | last_connect_error_number | last_connect_error_description | last_connect_error_timestamp | write_lease_remaining_ticks | current_configuration_commit_start_time_utc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2628da66-8831-41cb-bed5-44a17eb958bc | 52ea61a5-b557-49a1-9832-f9a8e992505d | 1 | 1 | PRIMARY | 2 | ONLINE | 1 | CONNECTED | 1 | ONLINE | 2 | HEALTHY | NULL | NULL | NULL | 10078 | NULL |
| 38cc5be4-8943-41da-a0af-4f1a07f23689 | 52ea61a5-b557-49a1-9832-f9a8e992505d | 0 | 2 | SECONDARY | NULL | NULL | 1 | CONNECTED | NULL | NULL | 2 | HEALTHY | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

| database_id | group_id | replica_id | group_database_id | is_local | is_primary_replica | synchronization_state | synchronization_state_desc | is_commit_participant | synchronization_health | synchronization_health_desc | database_state | database_state_desc | is_suspended | suspend_reason | suspend_reason_desc | recovery_lsn | truncation_lsn | last_sent_lsn | last_sent_time | last_received_lsn | last_received_time | last_hardened_lsn | last_hardened_time | last_redone_lsn | last_redone_time | log_send_queue_size | log_send_rate | redo_queue_size | redo_rate | filestream_send_rate | end_of_log_lsn | last_commit_lsn | last_commit_time | low_water_mark_for_ghosts | secondary_lag_seconds | quorum_commit_lsn | quorum_commit_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 52ea61a5-b557-49a1-9832-f9a8e992505d | 38cc5be4-8943-41da-a0af-4f1a07f23689 | 90fada18-1e06-4e8f-9e8f-2f94b41d0396 | 0 | 0 | 2 | SYNCHRONIZED | 1 | 2 | HEALTHY | NULL | NULL | 0 | NULL | NULL | 4294967295429490000000000 | 2425778000274270000000 | 2425984000038490000000 | 21-09-2023 14:08 | NULL | NULL | 2425984000038490000000 | 21-09-2023 14:08 | 2425984000038480000000 | 21-09-2023 14:08 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 34436 | 0 | 2425984000038480000000 | 2425984000038480000000 | 21-09-2023 14:08 | 9188127460 | 0 | NULL | NULL |
| 12 | 52ea61a5-b557-49a1-9832-f9a8e992505d | 2628da66-8831-41cb-bed5-44a17eb958bc | 90fada18-1e06-4e8f-9e8f-2f94b41d0396 | 1 | 1 | 2 | SYNCHRONIZED | 1 | 2 | HEALTHY | 0 | ONLINE | 0 | NULL | NULL | 4294967295429490000000000 | 2425778000274270000000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2425984000038490000000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2425984000038490000000 | 2425984000038490000000 | 21-09-2023 14:08 | 9188129173 | NULL | 2425984000038490000000 | 21-09-2023 14:08 |

sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_cluster_states

| replica_id | group_database_id | database_name | is_failover_ready | is_pending_secondary_suspend | is_database_joined | recovery_lsn | truncation_lsn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2628da66-8831-41cb-bed5-44a17eb958bc | 90fada18-1e06-4e8f-9e8f-2f94b41d0396 | REFLEX_PROD | 1 | 0 | 1 | 4294967295429496729500001 | 2425778000274275100001 |
| 38cc5be4-8943-41da-a0af-4f1a07f23689 | 90fada18-1e06-4e8f-9e8f-2f94b41d0396 | REFLEX_PROD | 1 | 0 | 1 | 4294967295429496729500001 | 2425778000274275100001 |

Comment: Please put the output of sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states and sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states from the primary replica for the AG with the databases having the truncation issues. Please don't assume what columns to include, use `select *`.

Comment: Updated the question with this info

Comment: Thanks - the output seems normal. Can you also add `sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_cluster_states` please.

Comment: Updated with the output of that table

Comment: That also seems to be correct. Please post the output of the following:
```--Run this on the primary
DBCC TRACEON(3604)

CREATE TABLE #TempResults
(
ParentObject sysname not null,
[Object]  sysname not null,
Field   sysname not null,
[Value]   nvarchar(100) not null
)

INSERT INTO #TempResults EXEC('DBCC DBTABLE(''DB_NAME_HERE_ON_PRIMARY'') WITH TABLERESULTS')

SELECT * FROM #TempResults WHERE [Object] like 'LogTruncMgr%'

DROP TABLE #TempResults

DBCC TRACEOFF(3604)```